# Jquery Queue Function

Tags: jquery, queue, delay

I am writing a slide show. I finally have a good function for showing only one slide. It shows it exactly like I want with shoSlide wait for a time and then hide slide. No that I have this good for one slide, my problem is doing it for many.

```
function slideShow() {
    console.log("countdown Slide Count: " + numberOfSlides);

    console.log("Current slide number: " + jslideNumber);

    $('#slide' + jslideNumber).fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).queue(function (next) {
        console.log("Hiding Slide Number: " + jslideNumber);
        $('#slide' + jslideNumber).fadeOut(1000);
        next();
    });
}

slideShow();
```

I tried putting into a WHILE loop but using either loop WHILE or FOR results in an infinite counter. I was incrementing jslideNumber++ before but the problem is that the loop increments the counter faster than the queue can fire. So when Slide1 is showing, normally Slide1 should hide, but instead, Slide1 shows and then it tries to hide Slide6 by the time the delay catches up to the counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"[id^=slide]"` selector , `$.map()` , `.dequeue()`

```js
var n = 150;

$.map(Array(n), function(val, index) {
  $("body").append("<div id=slide"+index+">"+index+"</div>")
})

$({}).queue("_fx", $.map($("[id^=slide]"), function(el) {
  return function(next) {
    $(el).fadeIn(1000, function() {
      $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000, next)
    })
  }
})).dequeue("_fx")
```

```css
[id^="slide"] {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: no you are rewriting the code. Kinda not what I was looking for. THere may be 100s of slides, so I need to do it like this.

Comment: @FunnyGirl See updated post, adjusted animation to `.fadeIn()` , `.fadeOut()` ; `[id^slide]` selects all elements where id begins with "slide" ; `$.map()` iterates `[id^slide]` elements, whether one or hundreds, waits for current animation to complete before calling `next` animation

Comment: @FunnyGirl You could also restart the animation at item 0 when all animations complete, to create an "infinite" loop